# What is the purpose of the "client ejb" module that can be generated when creating an ejb project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, client, ejb

As the title says, even with search i can't figure out the purpose of th "ejb client" module that can be generated when creating an ejb project , could anyone give me a tip? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the Netbeans IDE documentation:

> A Java EE application client is a stand-alone application that is configured to work as part of a Java EE enterprise application. Any Java application can access remote EJB methods and web services, so you do not necessarily have to create a Java EE application client to access your enterprise application. The advantage of accessing enterprise applications from enterprise application clients is that application clients have access to services and functionality running on the enterprise application server, while regular Java applications do not. For example, you can configure security roles and permissions for an enterprise application client.

So it's just a regular Java application which can be run inside the application server, accessing EJBs, as you could do even in plain Java standalone applications, but even application server services.